# Advice on Red Curly Brackets

Tags: apex, debugging, debug, compile-error

Does anyone have any advice on debugging someone else's code that has a number of red curly brackets? The code works so it's just me trying to clean it up. They are no longer with the company so I can't ask them for a quick fix and there are over 1000 lines of code. I typically would go through line by line but I didn't know if there was a quicker way. Any advice is appreciated!

[image: Red Closing Bracket]

Comment: What do you mean they're red? What editor are you using, and in what context are they red?

Comment: In the developer console. They turn green when they match up correctly and red when there is an compilation error.

Comment: I know it sounds crazy but everything is working and it passes all of the tests. I wanted to add to the page (I haven't yet) and when I was reviewing what they already had written, I noticed many 'red' curly brackets. I know they say don't fix what's not broken but I wanted to clean it up in case something was incorrect before I added in my content.

Comment: If someone asks you to modify a page whose controller has over 500 lines of code, let alone 1000, run away screaming. Waving your arms wildly for effect is also encouraged.

Comment: I've [already answered this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/developer-console-syntax-highlighting-some-brackets-red-some-green)...

Comment: For the record, this is a bug with the Developer Console. Other platforms, including BrainEngine, aside.io, Sublime/MavensMate, and the Force.com IDE all get it right.

Comment: haha @ adrianlarson I wish I could! but I need to add some functionality so I can't.
and thank you @sfdcfox, I appreciate you reiterating.